# Could someone translate text carved on my flute?

Tags: translation, poetry

could someone translate a text carved on my bamboo flute? I think it might be a poem :o

Here it goes, I took 2 photos in case it's not readible

[image] [image]

Also this one

[image]

I suppose it might be the creator's name?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "黃鶴樓中吹玉笛 江城五月落梅花", this is from Li Bai's poem.  
"龍秦", this may be person's name or location's name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

与史郎中钦听黄鹤楼上吹笛 李白
一为迁客去长沙，西望长安不见家。
黄鹤楼中吹玉笛，江城五月落梅花。

Translation is difficult for chinese poems, for charm will be lost for most times.
龙秦 is not the author, the author is 李白 the most famous poet wellknown as the poetic genius libai. 
The meaning of this poem is:

Demoted to Changsha, look west to Changan but there is no home there. Hearing jade flute play in the Yellow Crane Tower, seeing plums fall at may in Jiangcheng（Wuhan）.

Comment: Pretty good. It's all about feelings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's good to get the general idea what is written on my flute.

By the last photo, I meant the creator of the flute. I guess it might as well be a location where it was createad. Well either way it's not that important.